# What do you call the particular accent the secondary characters have?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the particular accent the secondary characters have? I am looking for the right word that refers to the accent of the secondary characters, they have what I would call a "peasant" accent, but I doubt that's what it's referred to by the people who are in the voice-acting community. I am not talking about the Witcher's accent, because he has a normal American English accent.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2IZYce-WxU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a "peasant" accent. It's seems to be some variation on the British Cockney accent, which is based in London.  It's used as a relatively standard "working class" accent.  I'm not enough of an expert to say for sure if it's a particular named variation, and it lacks some of the [vocalizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting) which appear in that dialect, as well 
as some of the its [more famous slang terms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NxQO2ZZjjE).

I'm not sure why the game producers have the other characters speak in British accents at all, although it's probably just because it sounds nice. As a contrast, [Yennefer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7ySzH0kDr0) speaks in a cultured, upper-class British accent. If they wanted to make these lower-class characters sound like peasants they might have used one of the more *rural* British accents, such as those from the middle or west of England.

In *Game of Thrones*, the characters from Winterfell all speak in a Northern English accent, to indicate remoteness from the main city (King's Landing) -- with Sansa Stark as a notable exception, possibly to indicate she was specially brought up to sound more like a "lady".

[Here's a rough overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyyT2jmVPAk) of some of the more well-defined British accents.